# KeyError: image_link key not found in Scrapy but present in items.py

Tags: python, scrapy, keyerror

My **items.py** looks like:

```
import scrapy

class NewsItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    pubDate = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
    image_link = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

And a **spider** used:

```
class Spider(BaseSpider):
    NO_IMAGE = "NoImageFound"
    name = '****'
    allowed_domains = ['****', '****']
    start_urls = [
        'http://*****',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('A response from %s just arrived!' % response.url)
        sel = Selector(response)
        _items = sel.xpath('//item')
        for item in _items:
            _item = NewsItem()
            _title = item.xpath('title/text()').extract()
            _item['title'] = ""
            if _title:
                _item['title'] = _title[0]

            #other stuffs here

            yield Request(_item['link'], callback=self.parse_detail, meta={'_item': _item})
            yield _item


    def parse_detail(self, response):
        _item = response.meta.get('_item')
        sel = Selector(response)
        try:
            _item['image_link'] = sel.select("//div[@class='article_content']/*/img/@src").extract()[0]
        except:
            try:
                _item['image_link'] = sel.select("//div[@class='entry']/descendant::node()/img/@src").extract()[0]
            except:
                _item['image_link'] = self.NO_IMAGE
        if _item['image_link'][0].endswith('gif'):
            _item = self.NO_IMAGE
        # _item['image_link'] = "TESTING"
        return _item
```

And in the **pipelines.py**

```
class NewsUploadPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        title = item['title'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        description = item['description'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        link = item['link'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        image_link = item['image_link'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

When I run the project, I get this:

```
File "/home/khadka/rkbnb/my_app/crawler/rkbnbcrawler/rkbnbcrawler/pipelines.py", line 16, in process_item
    image_link = item['image_link'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
  File "/home/khadka/rkbnb/my_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 56, in __getitem__
    return self._values[key]
KeyError: 'image_link'
```

**Output reports**

```
'log_count/DEBUG': 57,
 'log_count/ERROR': 27,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 2,
```

What is wrong? Clearly **image_link** exists in **items.py**. Any help or just hint is heartly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any other item classes defined?  Are you yielding items anywhere else in the spider?  Also, what's happening in `#other stuffs here`?  Are you doing any other item assignments?

Comment: @Rejected I have found the problem. Thank you . Will share it in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the problem**

The problem is the addition of `item['image_link']` is not being **passed back** to `parse` function.

**Solved**

I solved this using

```
_item = Request(_item['link'], callback=self.parse_detail, meta={'_item': _item})
yield _item
```

I guess that returned the changes to **_item** from `parse_detail` function.

Comment: That's the same as removing the `yield _item` line from your original problem.  In other words, `_item` is no longer being returned from the `parse` method, and will not go through the pipeline.  If that is your intent, then great.

Answer (score -1):

i think bug is at this part of the code :

```
        if _item['image_link'][0].endswith('gif'):
        _item = self.NO_IMAGE
```

at this case you overrite all the _item with self.NO_IMAGE

it should be :

```
        if _item['image_link'][0].endswith('gif'):
        _item['image_link'] = self.NO_IMAGE
```